# Lists in Xquery

Tags: list, xquery

Lets consider an example, a = 'red table jet blue ghost hind'. Now i want i as                 b = ['red', 'table', 'jet', 'blue', 'ghost', 'hind']. In python we can use list comprehension, but in Xquery is there any method like "List Comprehension" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XQuery is based on the **[XDM (XPath Data Model)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/)** in which there are **[*sequences*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#sequences)**.

A *sequence* is something like a flat list (it isn't possible to have a sequence of sequences).

**Here is an example**:

```
declare variable $a as xs:string := "red table jet blue ghost hind";  

declare variable $b as xs:string* := tokenize($a, ' ');
```

**And you can verify that `$b` is a sequence exactly of the wanted strings**:

```
declare variable $a as xs:string := "red table jet blue ghost hind";  

declare variable $b as xs:string* := tokenize($a, ' ');

for $s in $b
  return
    concat('"', $s, '"')
```

**When the above XQUery code is run, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
"red" "table" "jet" "blue" "ghost" "hind"
```